# / operation doesn't give me a resultat

Tags: c

Hello guys so basiclly i have this calculator in C , but whenever i try to 4/8 it gives me 0.000000 . Any help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
char action;
int number,number1;
float resultat;
do 
{
    printf ("Choisit votre opérateur logique\n");
    scanf("%c", &action);
} while (!((action == '/') ||(action == '-') ||(action == '+') ||(action == '*')  ));
switch (action)
{
    case '/':
    scanf("%d %d", &b,&c );
    resultat = number / number1;
    printf("Votre opéation a donné comme un résultat :  %f ", resultat);
    break;
```

(the code is uncomplete as the reset works fine and doesn't need any help) thanks

Comment: `4 / 8` *is* `0` in the world of integer arithmetic.

Comment: Now that you're sharing this code with others, you should edit it to be more readable to people who aren't as familiar with it (that includes yourself in 6 months, because you'll surely forget what you were thinking this morning). E.g. `a` should be `operation_symbol`, `b` and `c` could be `operand1` and `operand2`, `d` could be `result`, etc.

Comment: If you are writing a calculator, use `double`. In fact whenever you need floating point variables, use `double` unless you have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

In "C", dividing (or doing any other math operation) between integers will perform integer operation. For the case of division, it will truncate the result. You can force calculation into floating point by casting one of the arguments to float (or double)).

Without the cast, the code first calculate 4/8, resulting in (integer) 0, which is then converted to floating point 0.

```
    case '/':
    scanf("%d %d", &b,&c );
    d = ((float) b) / c;
    printf("Votre opéation a donné comme un résultat :  %f ", d);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `b` and `c` are integers so your program is performing integer division, which gives an integer result.

If you want this to perform floating-point division you need to cast your values to float when performing the division:

```
d = (float)b / (float)c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer division gives an integer result - if both `b` and `c` are integers and `b < c`, then `b / c` will yield `0`.

Declare all of `b`, `c`, and `d` as `double`, and use `%lf` to read `b` and `c`:

```
double b, c, d;
...
scanf("%lf %lf", &b,&c );
d = b / c;
```

Comment: Good catch.  The asymmetry between `printf` and `scanf` gets annoying at times.